# Running AppEngine locally (while debugging), how do I erase the data?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm working on a Google AppEngine project and I've changed my data format, so the old data needs to be wiped out. On AppSpot that's no problem: I use the data viewer to clobber it (the amount of data is small enough that I can use this). But how would I delete data from the local store (the data I see when I run it locally)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to specify one switch:

`dev_appserver.py --clear_datastore myapp`

Comment: Thanks! This didn't work for me (because the java development kit has no such switch) but it DID lead me to http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver.html#Using_the_Datastore which says I should just delete the file WEB-INF/appengine-generated/local_db.bin

Answer (score 1):

Try:

http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/